# Dax Calculated Column: Trying to return the value of previous row within a filtered table

Tags: dax, calculated-columns, powerpivot

I am attempting to create a Calculated Column that returns the previous row value of a table given a specific filter context.

I have attempted multiple different solutions on Google and I can not get this to work.
The issue is that Excel keeps locking up when I try to run certain DAX formulas, but only some of them and the lock ups are pretty consistent.

The formula I am running is this:

```
=
VAR RowID = Table1[ID]
VAR UserID = Table1[User - Username]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Table1[StopTime]),
    TOPN(
        1,
        FILTER(
            Table1,
            Table1[ID] < RowID
        ),
        Table1[ID],
        DESC
    ),
    Table1[User - Username] = UserID
)
```

The line that has "Table1[ID] < RowID" seems to be the culprit. I am trying to make the right most value of that line the Table[ID] column value of the row being calculated. I've tried to use EARLIER and EALRIEST, and they both lock up Excel as well.
If I replace the attempted row reference value with static value or something like MAX() it doesn't lock up, so I am convinced it has something to do with my attempt at referencing the row.

Here is a sample of the data I am trying to use and my desired Calculated Column:

| ID | User - Username | StopTime | Calculated Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12019496 | 37926 | 11/8/2022 17:02 | 11/8/2022 17:01 |
| 12019495 | 39095 | 11/8/2022 16:59 | 11/8/2022 16:55 |
| 12019494 | 37926 | 11/8/2022 17:01 | 11/8/2022 17:00 |
| 12019493 | 39095 | 11/8/2022 16:55 | 11/8/2022 16:51 |
| 12019492 | 37926 | 11/8/2022 17:00 | NULL |
| 12019491 | 39095 | 11/8/2022 16:51 | NULL |

Comment: Can you clarify your expected results? For example, if, as you say, the ID of the desired return has to be strictly less than the ID of the row being queried, how do you get a desired result of 11/8/2022 17:01 for the first row? That value belongs to ID 12019496, which is certainly not less than the ID of the entry in the row being queried (also 12019496).

Comment: Please provide **reasonable and representative** sample data to avoid endless discussions afterwards.

Comment: @JosWoolley My mistake, I was not careful when I was filling in the ID column of the table. The ID column is serialized, so each value is unique, but I want to be able to create a filter context for each User so that the Calculated Column shows the previous StopTime of the row User.

Comment: Not sure what your "specific filter context" refers to. Unlike Measures, Calculated Columns do not respond to slicers. That said, I would use simply `VAR RowID = Table1[ID] VAR UserID = Table1[User - Username] RETURN CALCULATE( MAX( Table1[StopTime] ), FILTER( Table1, Table1[ID] < RowID && Table1[User - Username] = UserID ) )`.